Diagnostics usage via CANoe and CAPL: Unable to trigger "on diagResponse" function
I'm trying to send a simulated Diagnostic response via CAPL, then catch it and do something with it.
This is the simulated response code (I can see it being sent in the Trace window):
on key 'z'
{
  byte rawData[5] = {0x62, 0xFE, 0x58, 0x01, 0x01};
  diagResponse TestECU.* resp;       
  diagResize(resp, elCount(rawData));
  diagSetPrimitiveData(resp, rawData, elCount(rawData));      
  diagSendResponse(resp); 

  write("response sent: %x, %x, %x, %x, %x", rawData[0], rawData[1],rawData[2],rawData[3],rawData[4]);}

Here is the response catcher:
on diagResponse TestECU.*
{
  byte data[4096];
  long size;
  diagResponse * resp; // declare response with no concrete interpretation
  size=this.GetPrimitiveSize(); // get length of response
  this.GetPrimitiveData(data, elcount(data)); // copy actual response from "on diagResponse *" into data array
  write("response from on diagResponse is %x, %x, %x, %x, %x", data[0], data[1], data[2], data[3], data[4], data[5]);}

From my understanding, this should work and I should be able to see the text in the write function (in the response catcher) displayed in the Write window, however it never triggers.
What I've tried:

separating the two blocks of code in different network nodes
catching all diag responses, by using on diagResponse *, without ECU specifier

I have a GenericUDS.cdd file generated, just to be able to run basic Diagnostics.
The network nodes are on the same CAN channel.
Note: I'm not writing/using the Test nodes and functionalities, just regular Network Nodes and basic CAPL.
Would greatly appreciate any advice, as I've ran out of ideas.

Could you show the values in the diagnostic configuration window? Are the CAN IDs, CDDs and nodes correct there?

I'm using a GenericUDS.cdd, generated through the Diagnostic Configuration window, just so I can have diagnostic functionality.
The CAN IDs are taken from the project documentation, I'd hope they are correct.
And for the nodes - I have the ECU qualifier assigned to the same CAN network, where the nodes are located.
I made screenshots of all of that, but unfortunately I cannot attach images to my posts.

Hard to tell, could be anything. How do you send the diagnostic request? CAPL? Diagnostic console?

I send it through CAPL, via this code block:
`on sysvar_update DiagInputs_Control::BUTTON_READ_INPUT_120
{  
    byte rawData[3] = {0x22, 0xFE, 0x58};
    diagRequest TestECU.* req;   
    diagResize(req, elCount(rawData));
    diagSetPrimitiveData(req, rawData, elCount(rawData));     
    diagSendRequest(req);
}`

**Wow I'm sorry for the formatting, I'm new to stack overflow and I'm having a hard time figuring out how to do it properly :D

Can't find anything obviously wrong. Do you see a correct interpretation of your request and response in the trace window? I.e. not only the CAN (and maybe ISO-TP) messages, but also diagnostic events? And BTW, you can always edit your question to add more information. Makes more sense than trying to cram everything into comments.

Yes, I can see the positive response being sent and the trace identifies it correctly as      ($22) ReadDataByIdentifier Process::pos, followed by the DID and colored in green.

Sounds good. Sorry, running out of ideas. What you could do is attach screenshots of diagnostic configuration, simulation setup, trace window, etc to your question. Maybe someone can spot something.
